# drawString not writing strings correctly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to make this GUI where there is a text field (the variable query below) and where the GUI will draw out the string that is typed into the text field if it notices that a key is pressed. However, if I initialize my string str to "" it stays as "" on the GUI and never changes, yet when I print out the string in the paintComponent method it has the correct string (except for the last character for some reason). Any tips? Thanks in advance!

```
private String str;
private JTextField query;
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        str = query.getText();
}
...
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //System.out.println(str);
        g.drawString(str,20,30);

}
```

Comment: Could you clarify why it would change?

Comment: Well, to start with, don't use a KeyListener with a text component, register a DocumentListener with the field. Make sure you are calling repaint when ever the DocumentListener is triggered...

Comment: `except for the last character for some reason` this is because keypressed event fire before character append to textfield.you can use keyrealesed.if you want to use keypressed then `query.getText()+e.getKeyChar()` will fix this problem but clarify rest of your question

Answer (score 4):

1. Don't use a `KeyListener` with any `JTextComponent`, it's not the appropriate method for monitoring changes to these components, instead use a `DocumentListener`, this will notify when the field is modified by call `setText` or if text is pasted into the field as well as when the user types something
2. Make sure you are repainting the component when the field is updated...

You should also avoid painting directly to the same component that you have components on, as the layout manager could put content over the top of your custom painting

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test1();
    }

    public Test1() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private String paintText;

        public TestPane() {
            JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
            add(field);
            field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                protected void update(DocumentEvent e) {
                    Document doc = e.getDocument();
                    try {
                        paintText = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
                        repaint();
                    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    update(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    update(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    update(e);
                }
            });
            field.setText("This is some text");
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(paintText)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) + fm.getAscent()) / 2;
            g2d.drawString(paintText, x, y);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```